# Get first td value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Beautifulsoup and Python, trying to figure how to get the first th tag of an HTML page. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

HTML

```html
<th width="10%">1365 m</th>
<th width="15%">Rating 25-0</th>
<th width="10%">12h45</th>
```

I would like to retrieve only the first width which has value 1365. Below is my code

```
print('Track '+soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'})[3])
```

I tried `find('th',{'width':'10%'})[3])` but it is throwing indexbound exception. Any help?
With my code i'm getting the second th tag which is 12h45

Comment: have you tried sth like find_all("th", class_="width")? this returns a list, from which you can select th first element

Comment: As a side note, why are you using `findAll` instead of `find_all`? That happens to work, despite the documentation saying it was removed, but you really shouldn't rely on that. More to the point, if you're learning from a tutorial for BS3 instead of BS4, you really want to find a newer and better tutorial (and likewise if you're copying and pasting BS3 code, etc.).

Comment: To get the last one, use this `soup.find_all('th',{'width':'10%'})[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`print(soup.findAll('th')[0])`

This is the first one.

Computers start **counting** from 0,1,2,3....n.
if you want to print the last one

`print(soup.findAll('th')[1])`

## Why

`soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'})[3]` **doesn't** work.

We're looking for **ALL** th's with the `width` of `10%`

In this HTML there's only two.

```
      <th width="10%">1365 m</th>
      <th width="15%">Rating 25-0</th>
      <th width="10%">12h45</th>
```

Best way is to print this:

```
for i in soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'}):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Last one is `print(soup.findAll('th')[2])`

Comment: Actually, it's `soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'})` it will find all instances of this `th` with the attribute `width` is exactly `10%`. If it finds only the ones with exactly `10%` there's only two (index `0,1`). Take care!

Comment: Then correct your answer. Why do you say that to print the last one is 'print(soup.findAll('th')[1])', when there are 3 'th' elements in OP example html?

Comment: [1] will print the second one ->       `<th width="10%">12h45</th> ` and the [0] will print      `<th width="10%">1365 m</th>` . Just wanted to make sure that he can extract a specific one by index doesn't to traverse the whole  tree.

Answer (score 0):

`soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'})[3]` should be:

```
# Get the all matching 'th' that also has 'width' set to  '10%', access the first match
print('Track '+soup.findAll('th',{'width':'10%'})[0])
```

or if you just want to access the first match:

```
# Get the first 'th' with 'width' '10%'
soup.find('th',{'width':'10%'})
```